# Ionic3 need to reload to show json

Tags: javascript, json, ionic3

I have a side project in **Ionic 3**. In this project I have view with array of users, this works perfectly. These users have a button with id, when we click we move to other view to show more data of this user. All backend is **Lumen** and tested with **Postman**, response is correct.

The problem that I have is that the second page doesn´t show any data, but I check in network tab and receive the json correctly. When I go back to first page and go again to the second page, data see in the view. ¿Why the first time that I go to the second page the data doesn´t appear? I think that is a strange error.

```
     data2: any
     verDetalles(id:any){
        this.visitantes.verVisitante(id)
        .then(data2 => {
          this.data2 = Array(data2);
        });
        this.navCtrl.push(DatosPreVisitasPage, {
          animate: true,
          data:this.data2
        });
      }

 //CALL TO ENDPOINT

  verVisitante(id:any) {    
    return this.http.get('http://visitas.api.app:8000/visitantes/'+id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise();
  }
```

And this code in view

```
<ion-header >
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title text-center>
      Datos Prevista
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding class="background">
  <ion-grid >
    <ion-card padding>
      <ion-list *ngFor="let user of datos" >
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Nombre</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.nombre" name="nombre"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Apellido</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.apellidos" name="apellido"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>Empresa</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.empresa" name="empresa"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label floating>DNI</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.dni" name="dni"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Maybe is a error on the promise or something like that, but not sure, i'm new in ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the second page inside `.then` so that it is called only when data has aarrived:

```
 data2: any
 verDetalles(id:any) {
    this.visitantes.verVisitante(id)
    .then(data2 => {
      this.data2 = Array(data2);

      this.navCtrl.push(DatosPreVisitasPage, {
      animate: true,
      data:this.data2
    });
   }); 
 }
```

Comment: WTF, how can´t I see that simple error? Anyway thank for help ^^